# Getting the latitude and longitude coordinates (to plot 2D) from a well survey

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, land-survey, azimuth, oil-gas

I basically want to do what you did here [How to create a layer of directional/horizontal wells?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52235/how-to-create-a-layer-of-directional-horizontal-wells).

I am able to get the coordinates from a well survey to create a shapefile to be able to visualize the "worm track" and from the coordinates get the middle point of the lateral length.

Comment: This completely depends on your input file, usually a well survey presents also a list of xy coordinates vs depth, do you have that info availabke or do you only have azimuth and dip values?

Comment: It looks like your question boils down to: "How to create a polyline shapefile from a list of coordinates, and get the midpoint", is that correct?